# Почему не открывается консоль в visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Написал простейшую программу, которая использует функцию printf() для вывода текста в консоль. Но при попытке запустить скомпилированную программу консоль не открывается, хотя программа запускается и висит в фоне. Причём, если кто знает, антивирус Avast (возможно как и другие антивирусы) имеет такую особенность - если попытаться запустить консольную программу, то он запускает свою как бы  безопасную консоль, в которой проверяет программу на вирусы. Так вот, при попытке запуска программы в vscode эта самая авастовская консоль запускается и в ней присутствует текст введённый в моей программе, но настоящую консоль vscode почему-то не открывает. Подскажите, в чём может быть причина?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h>

int main(){
    printf("123");
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Абсолютно некорректный вопрос. Какой язык программирования? Что вы делали? Причём здесь антивирусы? Пытались ли вы искать ответ в Google? Возможно вам поможет  перейти в vs code по   Вид -> Консоль отладки.

Comment: Абсолютно всё корректно. Какая вообще разница какой язык и тд., Смысл вопроса в том, что vscode не открывает консоль., хотя по косвенным признакам (консоли антивируса) консоль должна открываться, либо хотя бы выводится результат программы в терминал.

Comment: Вы не можете в полной мере понятно описать проблему, язык важен. Я всё ещё не понял причём здесь антивирус. Вы пытались его отключить? Вы пробовали воспользоваться run&debug? У вас корректно установлены компоненты для разработки на C? Раньше консоль присутствовала?

Comment: [Troubleshoot Terminal launch failures](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/troubleshoot-terminal-launch)

Comment: @DaYa антивирус видимо при том, что когда запускается приложение в IDE или VSCode, то обычно открывается терминал, где отображается ход выполнения приложения, бывает необходимость ввести какие-то значения и тп, ну и вместо дефолтного терминала видимо открывается авастовский.

Comment: @Simon у меня всегда при запуске программ, скомпилированных в ide открывается антивирусная консоль, а после неё обычная консоль. Но конкретно vscode обычную консоль не открывает.